# How to write data with a permanent header to a file in Python?

Tags: python

I want to write some simple data to a file using Python. There should be 1 permanent header which is `Date last Run` and under that header there is `date_file` which gets appended constatly. (`date_file` is a string which changes every time).

**This is my code:**

```
log_location = r'c:\data\OOP\Desktop\new_location'
with open(log_location + '\\' + 'logfile.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write('Date last Run')
    output.write(date_file)
```

This is my output:

```
Date last Run20200907
```

I want my output to be:

```
Date last Run
20200907
```

And when I run it on the 8th of September I want it to look like this:

```
Date last Run
20200907
20200908
```

etc. So the `date_file` gets appended under the previous last line and `Date last Run` should be permanent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always check to see how big the file is and write the header if it is empty:

```py
log_location = r'c:\data\OOP\Desktop\new_location'
with open(log_location + '\\' + 'logfile.txt', 'a') as output:
    if output.tell() == 0:
        output.write('Date last Run\n')
    output.write(date_file + '\n')
```